# What does the below code mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't understand what this code does:

```
.bind(this);
```

(I took this code from zurb foundation dropdown plugin)

```
.on('mouseleave.fndtn.dropdown', '[data-dropdown], [data-dropdown-content]', function (e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($this.data('dropdown')) {
          var settings = $this.data('dropdown-init');
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, $('#' + $this.data('dropdown')));
        } else {
          var target = $('[data-dropdown="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
              settings = target.data('dropdown-init');
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, $this);
        }
      }.bind(this), 150);
})
```

Is it compatible with jQuery 3?
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-bind-and-delegate

Comment: .bind - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: It will bind the `this` context to the function so `this` inside that function will always refer to `this` that is passed to `bind()` regardless of how the function is being called.

Comment: `compatible with jquery 3` - sure, because jQuery is just a javascript library, it doesn't change how javascript works

Comment: _it's compatible with jquery 3_ jQuery's `bind()` to bind event is deprecated. This is different from `Function#bind` in core JavaScript. To bind event in jQuery, use `on()`.

Comment: `bind(this)` doesn't really make sense here because coder already uses `$this` as closure.

Comment: @A.Wolff and `self` too.

Comment: This might help: http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` will set `this` inside the anonymous function to `this` of the from jQuery provided one.

Consider it like:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this); // "foo"
}.bind("foo"))();
```

[See the MDN documentation for more info ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

It has **nothing** to do with [`jQuery.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)!